# Javascript - changing text based on the repeatation of videos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code for something. Its difficult to explain so I'm thinking to share the link for easy the understanding.

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/timer/practice-shots.html

This is working fine completely cause i got help from stack overflow guys. If you notice what is happening in this work you can see repeating the same video three times. And it showing a text of "Practice shot 1" three times just before the video is playing. So what i need is, I need to change the text on every repeatation of video like,

"Practice shot 1" for first video 
"Practice shot 2" for second video and 
"Practice shot 2" for third video

Can we do that editing this script? Please help if you can. Thanks :)

```
var timeLeft = 3;
var videoCounter = 2;
var elem = document.querySelector('.countdown-content__count');
var timerId;

function countdown() {
  if (timeLeft == 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeOut();
    $(".video-wrapper span").fadeOut();
    var playPromise = $("#video")[0].play();
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;
  }
}

function practiceShot(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideUp(1000, function(){
          $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
              opacity: 0,
              display: 'inline-block'     
          }).animate({opacity:1},600);
          timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
          countdown();
        });
      }, 2000);
}
practiceShot();
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (videoCounter == 0) {
        return;
    }
    videoCounter--;
    timeLeft = 3;
    elem.innerHTML = "";
    $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeIn();
    $(".video-wrapper span").fadeIn();
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideDown(1000, function(){
          $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
              opacity:1,
              display: 'inline-block'     
          }).animate({opacity:0},600);
    });
    practiceShot();
}, false);
```

Comment: You can use yield for a generator function to go to the next values, simple example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Comment: Hey Raymond, let me try :) Thanks.

Comment: If you have video counter, why not just edit the text in the title to `Practice Shot ${videoCounter}`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hey Sagi, can you please check this link http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/timer/practice-shots.html ? Changing text is fixed. But showing timer circle in wrong position with text.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out that.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // ...
    videoCounter--;
    switch (videoCounter) {
        case 1:
            $('.countdown-content__head h3').text('Some thing you want.');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // ...
}, false);
```